# windows/mac users often cannot see that I added them to skype

Tags: skype

So I add some Windows or Mac User to Skype, I can see his profile and image. There is also a "cloud with question mark" next to his name meaning that he did not add me back.

I send users some messages, but I often get a reply "why didn't you add me, I am waiting you on Skype".

Is this a built-in bug in Skype? It will sometimes help if I resend invitation, but not always. The user has to be online if I want the 2nd approach to fix the issues.

Is there a cure to this? I am using Skype 4.3.0.37 (the latest one).

Comment: It's better to directly seek support from Skype.

Comment: Thought that someone has the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had it a few years back from Windows to Windows on the same LAN, so has nothing to do with Ubuntu/Windows/Mac. (probably a regression)

Back then the solution was: Delete user from both sides at the same time, restart Skype on both PC's and let the other one invite you now...  (When sitting next to each other, that's easy, but you're going to have a few expensive phone calls to make)